# Spark SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS and SPARK_LOCAL_IP on stand-alone cluster with docker containers

Tags: networking, apache-spark, docker

So far I have run Spark only on Linux machines and VMs (bridged networking) but now I am interesting on utilizing more computers as slaves. It would be handy to distribute a Spark Slave Docker container on computers and having them automatically connecting themselves to a hard-coded Spark master ip. This short of works already but I am having trouble configuring the right `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` (or `--host parameter` for start-slave.sh) on slave containers.

I think I correctly configured the `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` env variable to match the host machine's network-accessible ip (from 10.0.x.x address space), at least it is shown on Spark master web UI and accessible by all machines.

I have also set `SPARK_WORKER_OPTS` and Docker port forwards as instructed at http://sometechshit.blogspot.ru/2015/04/running-spark-standalone-cluster-in.html, but in my case the Spark master is running on an other machine and not inside Docker. I am launching Spark jobs from an other machine within the network, possibly also running a slave itself.

Things that I've tried:

1. Not configure `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` at all, slave binds to container's ip (like 172.17.0.45), cannot be connected to from master or driver, computation still works most of the time but not always
2. Bind to 0.0.0.0, slaves talk to master and establish some connection but it dies, an other slave shows up and goes away, they continue looping like this
3. Bind to host ip, start fails as that ip is not visible within the container but would be reachable by others as port-forwarding is configured

I wonder why isn't the configured `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` being used when connecting to slaves? I thought `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` would only affect on local binding but not being revealed to external computers.

At https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/connectivity_issues.html they instruct to "set `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to a cluster-addressable hostname for the driver, master, and worker processes", is this the only option? I would avoid the extra DNS configuration and just use ips to configure traffic between computers. Or is there an easy way to achieve this?

*Edit:*
To summarize the current set-up:

- Master is running on Linux (VM at VirtualBox on Windows with bridged networking)
- Driver submits jobs from an other Windows machine, works great
- Docker image for starting up slaves is distributed as a "saved" .tar.gz file, loaded (curl xyz | gunzip | docker load) and started on other machines within the network, has this probem with private/public ip configuration

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use containers? or were the containers just for a "sandbox" or "experimentation?"  By that I mean, are you trying to run many containers in parallel with a master on one container and just slaves in the others?  or, are you installing spark outside of containers all together?

Comment: Only slaves will be in Docker, master and driver are running "natively" on OS (but possibly in a VM). My slave docker image looks something like this (not quite up-to date): https://github.com/nikonyrh/docker-scripts/blob/master/spark_py34/Dockerfile

Basically it installs Python 3.4, numpy, scipy etc. we'll need for training our models in parallel. We need to scale on multiple slaves to get results faster and I thought a Docker image would be easy to deploy around and even on AWS.

Comment: FYI I also posted a question on https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3645#issuecomment-142319031, also related to https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3893

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found a solution for my use-case (one Spark container / host OS):

1. Use `--net host` with `docker run` => host's eth0 is visible in the container
2. Set `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` and `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to host's ip, ignore the docker0's 172.x.x.x address

Spark can bind to the host's ip and other machines communicate to it as well, port forwarding takes care of the rest. DNS or any complex configs were not needed, I haven't thoroughly tested this but so far so good.

Edit: Note that these instructions are for Spark 1.x, at Spark 2.x only `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` is required, I think `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` is deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

I am also running spark in containers on different docker hosts. Starting the worker container with these arguments worked for me:

```
docker run \
-e SPARK_WORKER_PORT=6066 \
-p 6066:6066 \
-p 8081:8081 \
--hostname $PUBLIC_HOSTNAME \
-e SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=$PUBLIC_HOSTNAME \
-e SPARK_IDENT_STRING=$PUBLIC_HOSTNAME \
-e SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=$PUBLIC_IP \
spark ...
```

where `$PUBLIC_HOSTNAME` is a hostname reachable from the master.

The missing piece was `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME`, an undocumented option AFAICT.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L904

Comment: `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME` is the exact config I've been searching for. Thank you!

Comment: This works for me with spark worker running in docker, connecting to master in a different network

Comment: Funnily enough, we made it work in the past with `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` but now, after some network changes, that doesn't work and `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME` does. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 12):

I'm running 3 different types of docker containers on my machine with the intention of deploying them into the cloud when all the software we need are added to them: Master, Worker and Jupyter notebook (with Scala, R and Python kernels).

Here are my observations so far:

**Master:**

- I couldn't make it bind to the Docker Host IP. Instead, I pass in a made up domain name to it: `-h "dockerhost-master" -e SPARK_MASTER_IP="dockerhost-master"`. I couldn't find a way to make Akka bind against the container's IP and but accept messages against the host IP. I know it's possible with Akka 2.4, but maybe not with Spark.
- I'm passing in `-e SPARK_LOCAL_IP="${HOST_IP}"` which causes the Web UI to bind against that address instead of the container's IP, but the Web UI works all right either way.

**Worker:**

- I gave the worker container a different hostname and pass it as `--host` to the Spark `org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Worker` class. It can't be the same as the master's or the Akka cluster will not work: `-h "dockerhost-worker"`
- I'm using Docker's `add-host` so the container is able to resolve the hostname to the master's IP: `--add-host dockerhost-master:${HOST_IP}`
- The master URL that needs to be passed is `spark://dockerhost-master:7077`

**Jupyter:**

- This one needs the master URL and `add-host` to be able to resolve it
- The `SparkContext` lives in the notebook and that's where the web UI of the Spark Application is started, not the master. By default it binds to the internal IP address of the Docker container. To change that I had to pass in: `-e SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="${VM_IP}" -p 4040:4040`. Subsequent applications from the notebook would be on 4041, 4042, etc.

With these settings the three components are able to communicate with each other. I'm using custom startup scripts with `spark-class` to launch the classes in the foreground and keep the Docker containers from quitting at the moment.

There are a few other ports that could be exposed such as the history server which I haven't encountered yet. Using `--net host` seems much simpler.

Comment: class to run worker is incorrect. it should be org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, instead of org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Worker.