# Docker: Connectivity between Physical Machine - VM -Docker container

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I have just started to have some experimentation with docker. 
On my Windows host I have a virtual machine which holds a docker container. I want to have a communication between host and container or may be other VMs and this container.

- Host ip is 192.168.2.10 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0
- VM ip is 192.168.254.130 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0
- Container gets an ip 172.17.0.13

I have seen few blogs talking about bridging but I am still not sure about it and how to do that. I am not very much into networking stuff.

A little guidance will help.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I followed this [bridge-building](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#bridge-building) but could not understand what ip range to give to bridge, so, I gave 192.168.254.1/24. The command `ip addr show bridge0` shows `state UNKNOWN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are using Docker on Windows with Linux host running on Virtualbox. Note that by default `docker-machine` creates a NAT adapter (with a port forward) and a host-only adapter, sometimes it is tricky to get different machines to talk to the correct ip.

As answered by Adrian you typically "publish" ports by port forwarding, but if your container has to communicate via many ports and you are only running one such container / host it could be easier to start the container via `docker run --net host ...`, this way host's ethernet adapters are directly visible within the container (as I discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737662/3731823)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Without --net host I am able to have communication from host to container. I guess if I do this I'll be able to have communication in reverse too. Is there a different way too to have container communicate with host ?

Comment: In my understanding host an any other machine can communicate with container if its port has been "published" with `-p` or `--publish` as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#binding-ports). My problem was that the container was using a complex protocol with multiple ports, so configuring them was tedious.

Also on some configurations many containers are run on the same host and ther ports are exposed to other containers but not to other external machines, this is the `EXPOSE` command at Dockerfiles or `--expose` when starting the container.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do this is just to publish a port on the container and use the IP of the VM e.g:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

Then visit the IP of the VM in a browser running on your host and you should get the webpage.

Comment: Thanks. I am already doing this but did not test the service. Its not a web service so I just PINGED the ip of container, which did not worked.
Anyways, its working without any change. But from container to host I think I have to follow @NikoNyrh advice or is there another way too?

Comment: Ping would work if the correct port is "published", I didn't bother to check which one. `netstat -peanut` is a very handy command to run on host and within the container to see how ports are being configured and listened to :)