# Is there an Apache Spark 2.0.0 public Docker image suitable for multi-node clustered deployment?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, cluster-computing

Looking for Apache Spark 2.0.0 Docker image ready to be pulled from any public repo, supporting clustering.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such image at the moment. Running Spark in Docker is tricky because of its network behavior:

- It opens a lot of ports, some decided dynamically (for TorrentBroadcast).
- It wants to advertise its host name to be able to receive incoming connections from the executors.

I could not find a ready-made image and I gave up solving the above issues. I went with the workaround of running my Spark application in Docker with **host networking**.

Comment: I also ended up using "host" networking, in addition [I set](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32737662/3731823) `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` and `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to match the host's own ip (address like 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x). Without it Spark might advertise and/or bind to the docker's 172.x.x.x ip instead.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can point me to the issues you have faced so far using docker 

Have you tried to use Kubernetes to solve he networking issue you faced?

Comment: I have not tried Kubernetes. The issues I faced I found also described in http://sometechshit.blogspot.hu/2015/04/running-spark-standalone-cluster-in.html. That blog post also suggests solutions and I tried following along, but at some point I gave up and just switched to host networking. It works fine with no extra tuning. (I did not set `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` and `SPARK_LOCAL_IP`.)